# Typos in HoTT appendix A.1.2?

Tags: logic, type-theory, homotopy-type-theory, univalent-foundations

I've started reading the HoTT book and am trying to understand its formal treatment of Martin-Löf type theory. Something small in the "first presentation" of the appendix has tripped me up; see the screenshot attached below for reference. In particular, the last two "alternative style" rules are not entirely clear to me. For one, surely the second should read "if $x:A\vdash b:B(x)$ then $\lambda x.b:\Pi_{(x:A)}B(x)$"? This seems to me a rather important point as $B$ and $B(x)$ are distinct terms. For the other, surely the third holds only if $x$ does not occur free in $B$? This may be implicit but it seems unclear to me.

[image]

Comment: @DanielSchepler I was considering this as well, but surely that interpretation would then make the *first* alternative style rule incorrect? In that one aren't we considering "$B(x)$" as the term obtained by an application instance applied to $B$ and to $x$?

Comment: Oh, I missed that you were looking at the "alternative style" rules at the end, not the first set of rules.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Oh no worries, my bad. Do you have any insight on my question? I feel like I might be missing something obvious but am not sure

Comment: I think you're right on both counts - in fact I'd put the restriction that $x$ is not free in $B$ on all three rules.  (Though to be honest, for foundations I usually prefer using de Bruijn indices to avoid these types of shadowing issues altogether, and let the versions with named symbols be treated as purely syntactic sugar.)

Comment: @DanielSchepler Fantastic, thank you so much! Definitely agree re: de Bruijn indices

Comment: This typo [is known](https://github.com/HoTT/book/issues/1046). It's probably worth just opening a pull request to fix it.

Comment: @SCappella right on, thank you!